# Mouse misbehaving in lubuntu while it was working fine in windows 7

Tags: mouse, lubuntu

My Dell N-5030 PC is encountering issues with the mouse in Lubuntu, despite its smooth functionality on Windows 7.

I've already attempted driver updates through the terminal using commands like `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. However, the problem persists.

I've also tried different USB ports and restarted the computer, yet the mouse misbehavior persists. I'd appreciate guidance on adjusting Lubuntu's mouse settings to ensure they align with my preferences.

Comment: What issues are you encountering? Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/763065/edit) to tell us